# Lucene - Expected behavior when indexing multiple occurrences of a token within a field

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

Lets say that I'm indexing a string value "useridA;useridB,userdidC,useridA,useridA"

The field is set to ANALYZED and uses a custom CharTokenizer which looks for a boundary comma char.
What is the expected behavior in the index, as the token "useridA" occurs multiples times within the same field?

Will it just re-index the same value an preserve the same space as if it would have been just one occurrence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the basic level lucene is an "inverted term index" it stores term->docID. So if a term occurs many times it'll only be recorded once.

Obviously this is a huge simplification. Positional information will also be stored depending on the [TermVector](https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_0_3/api/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.TermVector.html) value used when adding the field (you will need this to use phrase and slop queries).

Depending only your use-case I'd suggest you de-dupe the list either when indexing or just use a HashSet< string> for that property of whatever your class is.